How can I add worker node [TLS handshake timeout]?
I have a ubuntu-based master machine where I have a microk8s cluster running.
I wanted to add an rpi as a worker node. microk8s join worked and replied with
Waiting for this node to finish joining the cluster. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..
Successfully joined the cluster.

But running microk8s kubectl get nodes on the worker node shows problems with the TLS handshake:
E0906 17:40:05.487052   89509 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://127.0.0.1:16443/api?timeout=32s": net/http: TLS handshake timeout

Also, on the master, when listing nodes only the master is shown. When trying to hit the ports from the worker on the master, everything seems fine (nc gives Connection to 10.0.0.101 16443 port [tcp/*] succeeded!).
Any ideas whats wrong here?

Refer to the similar issue on Github link and also go through this Stack link which might be helpful for you.

Ok, got if working, completely my fault. I simply forgot the --worker-flag when doing the join-command on the worker node.
